# Submit html form with POST and wamp UPDATED

Tags: php, html, forms

Trying to send test email, below is the code for the html form and php code. I'm trying to send the email using wamp. I've updated the php.ini file. The below code displays above my message as soon as the page is displayed.

```
Your message has been sent!</p>';
    } else { 
        echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
    } 
    } }
    ?>
```

Also, my php code is directly above my form code in the same file. When I fill out the form and submit, it looks like it submits, but I never get the email.

Please help, I'm dying here.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$from = 'From: Cruser Computers Website'; 
$to = 'mcruser@crusercomputers.com'; 
$subject = 'Hello';

$body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Phone: $phone\n Message:\n $message";

if ($_POST['submit']) {              
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
    echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
} else { 
    echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
} 
} }
?>

<form id='contact-form' action='' method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div class="success">
    Contact form submitted!<br>
    <strong>We will be in touch soon.</strong>
    </div>
        <fieldset>
    <label class="name">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="Name:">
    <span class="error">*This is not a valid name.</span> <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span> 
    </label>
    <label class="email">
    <input type="text" name="email" value="E-mail:">
    <span class="error">*This is not a valid email address.</span> <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span>
    </label>
    <label class="phone">
    <input type="tel" name="phone" value="Phone:">
    <span class="error">*This is not a valid phone number.</span> <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span>
    </label>
    <label class="message">
    <textarea name="message">Message:</textarea>
    <span class="error">*The message is too short.</span> <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span>
    </label>
    <div class="buttons-wrapper">
    <a class="button" data-type="reset">Clear</a>
    <a class="button" name="submit" data-type="Submit">Submit</a>
    </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: what browser are you using because it worked for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed quite a bit but it works for me finally. The html should require each input to be filled now. The PHP checks if anything is submitted by checking that the value of the email input is not blank. I did a bit of styling as well.

**EDIT:**
Now nothing gets displayed on load!

Changed:

```
if($_POST['email'] !== '') {
```

To this:

```
if($_POST['email'] !== '' and isset($_POST['email'])) {
```

**PHP Final edited code**

```
<?php
//If the email is not blank
if($_POST['email'] !== '' and isset($_POST['email'])) {
    //Email isn't blank so we can define are vars and sent the message
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $from = 'From: Cruser Computers Website'; 
    $to = 'mcruser@crusercomputers.com'; 
    $subject = 'Hello';
    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Phone: $phone\n Message:\n $message";

    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
        echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
    }else{ 
        //Problem with sending mail
        echo '<p>Message could not be sent!</p>'; 
    } 
}
?>

<form id='contact-form' action='' method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset>
    <label class="name">
    <input type="text" name="name" required placeholder="Name:"> 
    </label>
    <br>
    <label class="email">
    <input type="text" name="email" required placeholder="E-mail:">
    </label>
    <br>
    <label class="phone">
    <input type="tel" name="phone"  required placeholder="Phone:">
    </label>
    <br>
    <label class="message">
    <textarea placeholder='Message' name="message"></textarea>
    </label>
    <div class="buttons-wrapper">
    <input type="reset" value="Clear">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort on this, but I'm still seeing the echo lines above my form as soon as the page displays.

Comment: What does it display? and does the script work for you?

Comment: Your message has been sent!
'; }else{ //Problem with sending mail echo '
Message could not be sent!

'; } } ?>

Comment: the email will not send. I think it hs something to do with the smtp auth. through wamp server. I'm trying to get the site hosted on GoDaddy and use the formmail appto get the email to send.

Answer (score 0):

The php file must be in a different file from the html. Base on your code, the php could be in the same folder as your html folder.

Answer (score 0):

That's all what I could come up with, and I tested it in 3 major browsers(chrome, mozila and IE11).

1. Submit is not a link, it's an input!
2. Don't put the success message in the top of your form, but include it under the "if(isset...)' function so it will be displayed only if the form was submitted.
3. the form should be displayed only if the user didn't submit his message.

   ```
   <?php

   //If the email is not blank
   if($_POST['email'] !== '' and isset($_POST['email'])) {
   //Email isn't blank so we can define are vars and sent the message
   $name = $_POST['name'];
   $email = $_POST['email'];
   $message = $_POST['message'];
   $phone = $_POST['phone'];
   $from = 'From: Cruser Computers Website'; 
   $to = 'mcruser@crusercomputers.com'; 
   $subject = 'Hello';
   $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Phone: $phone\n Message:\n $message";
   if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
       echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
   }
   else{ 
       //Problem with sending mail
       echo '<p>Message could not be sent!</p>'; 
   } 
    }
    else{

    echo '<form id="contact-form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <fieldset>
       <label class="name">
       <input type="text" name="name" required placeholder="Name:"> 
        </label>
        <br>
   <label class="email">
   <input type="text" name="email" required placeholder="E-mail:">
   </label>
   <br>
   <label class="phone">
   <input type="tel" name="phone"  required placeholder="Phone:">
   </label>
   <br>
   <label class="message">
   <textarea placeholder="Message" name="message"></textarea>
   </label>
   <div class="buttons-wrapper">
   <input type="reset" value="Clear">
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
   </div>
   </fieldset>
   </form>';
    }
   ```

if you still have problems then you will have to check the way you updated your php.ini file. Here is a picture of the form we have here:
[image: email submission]

Answer (score 0):

Include this line of code at the begging of the page .Hope it will work!

```
<?PHP
error_reporting(0);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code above your form

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$from = 'From: Cruser Computers Website'; 
$to = 'mcruser@crusercomputers.com'; 
$subject = 'Hello';

$body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Phone: $phone\n Message:\n $message";

if ($_POST['submit']) {              
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
    echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
} else { 
    echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
} 
} }
?>
```

Comment: I paste the code you gave and the below code is displayed above my form on the site:

Comment: Your message has been sent!</p>';
} else { 
    echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
} 
} }
?>